# email users who have a value of 1 in mysql field

Tags: php, mysql

I have a php file that is executed every night at midnight. It queries mysql for all user in a table if they have a value of "1" in the alerts field and it returns their email addresses. I am trying to get this file to only email those users. currently i have it working by emailing every single email address in the database `$to = $row['email'];` but I cant get it to only send emails to the select users who have signed up for alerts.

```
<?

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","DB1");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
 echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users");



##email users their account balances


$sql = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE alerts = '1'");
$recipients = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 

    $recipient[]=$row['email'];

    $to = $row['email'];
    $subject = "Your account has received a deposit.";
    $body = "Hello,\n\nWe have added 1 DOGE and .0000001 BTC to your account. Go to www.bitcoinchew.com/Profile to withdrawl. $
    if (mail($to, $subject, $body)) {
        echo("<p>Email successfully sent!</p>");
    } else {
        echo("<p>Email delivery failed…</p>");
    }
  }
?>
```

Comment: Your `while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ ` is selecting from `$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users");` NOT `$sql = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE alerts = '1'");`. Edit one of these and remove the other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here. Firstly, you're calling the wrong variable `$result` for your query and using `mysqli_query()` twice.

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users");
```

and

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
```

Get rid of `$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users");`

and use `$sql = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE alerts = '1'");`

then using `while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){` instead.

You're also missing a `From:` in your [**`mail()` headers**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php), which would most likely end up in Spam or be "marked" as Spam. The `From` would show up as your server, rather than an Email address.

```
$from = "you@example.com";
```

then add `$headers,` in `if (mail($to, $subject, $body))` being

```
if (mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers))
```

You also had a missing quote and semi-colon at the end of `to withdrawl. $` which would have resulted in a parse error.

`to withdrawl. $";`

---

Here's a working rewrite:

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","DB1");

    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
     echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

$sql = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE alerts = '1'");

$recipients = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){ 

    $recipient[]=$row['email'];

    $from = "you@example.com"; // <= change it to your own

    $to = $row['email'];
    $subject = "Your account has received a deposit.";

    $body = "Hello,\n\nWe have added 1 DOGE and .0000001 BTC to your account. Go to www.bitcoinchew.com/Profile to withdrawl. $";

    $headers = "From: $from";


    if (mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers)) {
        echo("<p>Email successfully sent!</p>");
    } else {
        echo("<p>Email delivery failed…</p>");
    }
}
```

---

**Footnotes:**

`$recipients = array();` is not required. You can just need to remove the brackets `$recipient=$row['email'];`

Both methods will work either way, it's just more keystrokes for nothing.

---

**Personalization:**

If you have a row for people's names, you can personalize it with:

`$name=$row['name'];` add it above `$recipient=$row['email'];`

then doing `$body = "Hello $name,\n\nWe have added...`

Answer (score 0):

Your while loop should read

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){ ...
```

Comment: OP is missing the connection in `$sql` -> `$sql = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE alerts = '1'");` should be `$sql = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE alerts = '1'");`